# Image and Button title in VStack button

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Code below in xcode swiftui will generate the **BEFORE** screen but **I want to move the House image just above the "Houses" text (see AFTER screen)**, I have spent a full day on this and I can't figure out how to make it possible, if anyone is willing to step in for help will be much appreciated! Full code provided below...

[Before and After VStack button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lDtI.png)

```
import SwiftUI

struct LightGreenButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Image(systemName: "house")
              .resizable()
              .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
              //.opacity(0.6)
              .clipped()
              .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.005, green: 0.4422248602, blue: 0.3870742321, alpha: 1)))
              .offset(x: 0, y: 0)


            Text("Houses")
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                .frame(width: 150, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.005, green: 0.4422248602, blue: 0.3870742321, alpha: 1)))
                .background(
                    ZStack {
                        Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.6574724317, green: 0.8923466802, blue: 0.8671938181, alpha: 1))

                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16, style: .continuous)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .blur(radius: 4)
                            .offset(x: -8, y: -8)

                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16, style: .continuous)
                            .fill(
                                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.6574724317, green: 0.8923466802, blue: 0.8671938181, alpha: 1)), Color.white]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
                        )
                            .padding(2)
                            .blur(radius: 1)
                    }


                )

                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16, style: .continuous))
                .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8696053624, green: 0.8697276711, blue: 0.8695667386, alpha: 1)), radius: 20, x: 20, y: 20)
                .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)), radius: 20, x: -20, y: -20)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9447055279, green: 0.954059048, blue: 0.954059048, alpha: 1)))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct LightGreenButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LightGreenButton()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4.

[image: demo]

```
struct LightGreenButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Image(systemName: "house")
              .resizable()
              .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
              //.opacity(0.6)
              .clipped()
              .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.005, green: 0.4422248602, blue: 0.3870742321, alpha: 1)))
              .offset(x: 0, y: 0)


            Text("Houses")
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.005, green: 0.4422248602, blue: 0.3870742321, alpha: 1)))
        }
        .frame(width: 150, height: 100)
        .background(
            ZStack {
                Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.6574724317, green: 0.8923466802, blue: 0.8671938181, alpha: 1))

                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16, style: .continuous)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .blur(radius: 4)
                    .offset(x: -8, y: -8)

                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16, style: .continuous)
                    .fill(
                        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.6574724317, green: 0.8923466802, blue: 0.8671938181, alpha: 1)), Color.white]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
                )
                    .padding(2)
                    .blur(radius: 1)
            })

            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16, style: .continuous))
            .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8696053624, green: 0.8697276711, blue: 0.8695667386, alpha: 1)), radius: 20, x: 20, y: 20)
            .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)), radius: 20, x: -20, y: -20)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9447055279, green: 0.954059048, blue: 0.954059048, alpha: 1)))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```